# Retention period and tags are only added to single region of lambda@edge log groups while using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform script that creates a lambda@edge function using terraform module `"terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"`.

I added a tags, retention period to the lambda log group as in the code below. The retention period and subscriptions are only added to single region of log groups, but not for all. How can i configure it to add tags, and retention period for log groups from all regions?

```
module "origin_request_lambda_at_edge" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  lambda_at_edge  = true
  function_name   = local.lambda_origin_request_name
  description     = "${var.app_tag} viewer request lambda@edge function for ${var.env_tag} environment"
  handler         = var.handler
  runtime         = var.run_time
  source_path     = "${var.main_function_folder_name}/${var.request_function_folder_name}"
  cloudwatch_logs_retention_in_days  = 60
  cloudwatch_logs_tags = {
    Name  = "${local.lambda_origin_request_name}-logs"
    App   = var.app_tag
    Environment = var.env_tag
  }
  tags = {
    Name  = "${local.lambda_origin_request_name}-lambda-edge"
    App   = var.app_tag
    Environment = var.env_tag
  }
}
```

Comment: The module appears to have a bug where it only creates the log group named `us-east-1`. Looking at the code for the Terraform module, I believe the authors of the module looked at this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-logs.html and mistakenly thought that the `us-east-1` in the log group name was supposed to be hard-coded, because they have hard-coded it in the module if you have `lambda_at_edge = true`. You should post a bug report on the module's GitHub issues: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/issues

Comment: Are there other modules that i can use which functions as expected?

Comment: The problem is that the Terraform AWS provider will only work with one AWS region at a time. You would have to define a new Terraform AWS provider instance for each AWS region your function might run in, and define a separate CloudWatch Logs group for each of those regions. If you want to do this, I suggest you do this yourself in your Terraform code instead trying to find a module that will do it for you. Modules can't really do this for you.